# opal client is very slow

Tags: opa, opal

I'm using OPAL(Open Policy Administration Layer) .
OPAL is fetching rego files from gitlab and I have about 200 rego files in gitlab.
when opal-client is started, it has 4 minutes to start up the opal-client. It's too slow.
Is there any way to speed up the start up process　when there are a large number of rego files?

Comment: Consider caching the compiled results of your rego files. If possible, parallelize the loading and processing of rego files. lastly Minimize external dependencies or network calls during startup

Comment: Thank you for the response @tousifNoor .  How can I cache the compiled results?